# Norm $L^2$ of a multivariate function

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, normed-spaces

I know that the $2$-norm of a function $f(x)$ of one real variable is:

$$||f(x)||_2 = \bigg (\int_x f(x)^2 dx \bigg )^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

How does this extend to a multivariate function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable map, we define

$$\|f\|_2 := \left( \int_{\Bbb R^n} |f(x_1, \dots, x_n)|^2 dx_1 \cdots dx_n \right)^{1/2}$$

This can be generalized to the $p$-norm for any $1≤p<\infty$, so that we can define the spaces $L^p(\Bbb R^n)$.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, so I can ask another question if need be: I'd like to set up a variational equation so that I can obtain a function $\vec{x}(t)$ that minimizes that norm.  Any ideas on what that equation would be?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky: even with more context, I'm not sure I would be able to give a satisfactory answer to your question. You could maybe ask a new question for that.

Comment: More generally, if $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is a measurable map, then we can define
$\|F\|_2 := \left( \int_{\Bbb R^n} \|F(x_1, \dots, x_n)\|^2 dx_1 \cdots dx_n \right)^{1/2}$ where $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^p$ (they are all equivalent).

Comment: Done!  It made me wait for 15 minutes before I could :-P

Comment: @Watson What about vectors like $||\nabla u||$? Is this the dot product of the vector with itself, or do we use the above definition? (I think it should be the dot product). Did I also understand correctly that the absolute value is useless here, only needed for complex values?